# Review the application state (variable values) before crash to desktop CDT

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

This is for a Windows Forms application

I'd like to know how would be possible to know the state of the application (variables, properties) in an application, when it crashes.

I remember once I saw that Visual Studio had a feature like that, which allowed you to "revive" the moment after crash within VS (I guess some file is dumped and then given to VS), just I don't know how to search for it (if it really exist)

The user feedback is bad and doesn't help us, so the idea would to be able to catch whatever the tests didn't catch, and being able to know what was the status prior to CTD.

We are trying at this moment to use log4net + Postsharp free, but we were thinking that there should be a better option for this.

We don't know how to search for it, please could you help us?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So, the feature I was looking for is called IntelliTrace, and comes with Visual Studio Ultimate.

That will allow to take a snapshot of the entire flow of your application, variables (**only primitives**), call stack, etc. It works for Web, Sharepoint and managed (.NET) applications.

If someone is interested, then it's possible to find the guide to make it work at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh398365(v=vs.110).aspx, follow the process depicted there!

In order to improve performance, I'd suggest to edit the collection plan, and remove **all third party assemblies that you don't need to trace**!, this can be done thru their PublicKeyToken or the assembly name (.DLL or .EXE)

As an example:

```
    <!-- Telerik (all controls share it) -->
    <Name>PublicKeyToken:5BB2A467CBEC794E</Name>
    <!-- Zen.Barcode -->
    <Name>PublicKeyToken:B5AE55AA76D2D9DE</Name>
    <!-- MS WSE 3.0 -->
    <Name>PublicKeyToken:31bf3856ad364e35</Name>
    <!-- Iconic.zip -->
    <Name>PublicKeyToken:EDBE51AD942A3F5C</Name>
    <!-- GDPicture 1 -->
    <Name>PublicKeyToken:8585D00CF40C0F9F</Name>
    <!-- GDPicture 2 -->
    <Name>PublicKeyToken:1CB70661D884636D</Name>
    <!-- GDPicture 3 -->
    <Name>PublicKeyToken:E8BB32F622D7E512</Name>
```

Now, to launch your app and IntelliTrace it, you can do something like:

```
C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe launch /cp:"C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.*App*.xml" /f:"C:\IntelliTraceLogFiles\*App_%date%_%username%_%RANDOM%*.itrace" "C:\Path\To\Your\*App*.exe"
```

That will collect everything, on itrace files, named ***App*******YourDate*******UserName***_***SomeRndNumberHere***.itrace, including exceptions, which you can later on open on visual studio to diagnose.